# How can I read 1.0.0.0/24 as a range (1.0.0.0 to 1.0.0.24) in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**----------------------- ORIGINAL QUESTION -----------------------**

Assume I have IP `1.0.88.12`. I want to query against an IPv4 database and return the correct country.

The database (`geodata`) table (`IP`) is listing IPs in the following format:

```
network       country
---------------------
1.0.0.0/24     1212
1.0.1.0/24     1212
...            ...
1.0.88.0/22    3000
```

Here, I assume that `1.0.88.0/22` represents `1.0.88.0`, `1.0.88.1`, `1.0.88.2` to `1.0.88.22`.

How can I query this table so that it understands that each `network` is in fact, a range?

**----------------------- PROGRESS UPDATE -----------------------**

So I was wrong in my assumption, thanks for all the input! Still one question outstanding though.

Take the following example (of what I now have):

```
/**
 * Convert IP 4-octed set into integer
 */
create function [dbo].[IPAddressToInteger] (@IP as varchar(15))
returns bigint
as
begin
 return (convert(bigint, parsename(@IP,1)) +
         convert(bigint, parsename(@IP,2)) * 256 +
         convert(bigint, parsename(@IP,3)) * 256 * 256 +
         convert(bigint, parsename(@IP,4)) * 256 * 256 * 256)
end


/**
 * Calculate CIDR from mask
 */
create function [dbo].[CIDRFromMask] (@mask as bigint)
returns varchar(5)
as
begin
     declare @maskCalc bigint
     select  @maskCalc = dbo.IPAddressToInteger('255.255.255.255') - @mask + 1

     declare @logCalc int
     select  @logCalc = (32 - log(@maskCalc, 2))

     return '/' + cast(@logCalc as varchar(5))
end

select dbo.IPAddressToInteger('195.65.254.11'); -- 3275881995
select select dbo.CIDRFromMask('3275881995');   -- /2

select '195.65.254.11/2' from geodata.IP        -- 0 results
select '195.65.254.0/2'  from geodata.IP        -- 1 result (seems correct)
```

The point is: if I concatenate IP + CIDR I don't find a corresponding IP in the geo database (which afaik is a complete database). If I manually convert `195.65.254.11/2` into `195.65.254.0/2` it does find a result, but I don't think this is the way to go. Hence: **which step am I still missing?**

Comment: Note that the address `1.0.88.0/22` would usually mean "the first 22 bits are the network", not that the range is `1.0.88.1`-`1.0.88.22`. Is that your own IP range format, or are you just misunderstanding the CIDR notation? Given that it's a geodata table, I'd expect the networks would be CIDR, so `1.0.0.0/24` would map to `1.0.0.1`-`1.0.0.255`.

Comment: are you sure this is what you need to do ? Read about [Subnetting here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) => `Section 'Subnet and host counts'`

Comment: or [read about the CIDR notation here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation)

Answer (score 2):

You might try converting the IP ranges to Int32. This way it could be easier to query these intervals.
You can refer to the following link for a general idea:
https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/comparing-ip-addresses-in-sql.html

Comment: One still has to convert obliques to ranges.  That reference doesn't cover this for sql server.

Answer (score 1):

If it's actually CIDR notation, you can convert into int as proposed @Doğukan Tunç apply mask and compare with address part of CIDR. Probably will be good idea to make function, taking 2 arguments - IP and CIDR returning bit value (0 or 1)
Here is just illustration code making the job, not function. Errors are not handled, assumed IP address and CIDR are valid

```
declare @IP nvarchar(20)='192.168.1.111';
declare @CIDRADDR nvarchar(20)='192.168.0.0/22';


--convert to int
declare @IP_as_int bigint;
select @IP_as_int=convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 1)) +
    convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 2)) * 256 +
    convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 3)) * 65536 +
    convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 4)) * 16777216;

--calculate mask from CIDR: can specify table, or use CASE or use cycle
--mst performance will have CASE, but am to lazy to write CASE with 32 cases  
--the result should be N filled bits from left side of 32-bit integer, where N is number after / in CIDR notation
declare @mask bigint=0;
declare @m1 bigint
declare @m2 bigint=0x80000000;
select @m1=CHARINDEX('/',@CIDRADDR);
select @m1=cast(SUBSTRING(@CIDRADDR,@m1+1,2)  as int);

while(@m1>0)
begin
    set @mask = @mask | @m2;
    set @m2=@m2 /2;
    set @m1=@m1-1;
end



--calculate back
declare @IP_as_bin binary(4)=cast(@IP_as_int & @mask as binary(4));
declare @maskedIP nvarchar(20)= cast(cast((substring(@IP_as_bin,1,1)) as int) as nvarchar)+'.'  +
    cast(cast((substring(@IP_as_bin,2,1)) as int) as nvarchar)+'.'  +
    cast(cast((substring(@IP_as_bin,3,1)) as int) as nvarchar)+'.' + 
    cast(cast((substring(@IP_as_bin,4,1)) as int) as nvarchar);

--compare with CIDR address part
select @m1=CHARINDEX('/',@CIDRADDR);
if(SUBSTRING(@CIDRADDR,1,@m1-1)=@maskedIP)
    print @IP + ' belongs to ' +@CIDRADDR;
else
    print @IP + ' doesn`t belong to ' +@CIDRADDR;
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the idea by @Dogucan

First of all I convert the IP character string into an integer (ignoring the "/24"). I use the "/" portion to determine how many bits are used for the network route, in this case 24. I use this to find how many bits are used for the IP address. In this case it is 32-24 = 8. 8 bits equates to a range of 2^8 = 256 (since IP's are zero based I take 1 off to give me an IP Range of 0..255).

I then add this to my original IP address to get the end IP and convert it back into a string.

```
declare @ip varchar(50) = '1.0.0.0/24'


;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        convert(bigint, SUBSTRING(parsename(@ip, 1),0, CHARINDEX('/',parsename(@ip, 1)))) +
      convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 2)) * 256 +
      convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 3)) * 65536 +
      convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 4)) * 16777216 as StartIPInt,
      convert(bigint, SUBSTRING(parsename(@ip, 1),0, CHARINDEX('/',parsename(@ip, 1)))) +
      convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 2)) * 256 +
      convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 3)) * 65536 +
      convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 4)) * 16777216 + 
      POWER(2,32- convert(bigint, SUBSTRING(parsename(@ip, 1),CHARINDEX('/',parsename(@ip, 1))+1,20)))-1 AS EndIpInt
)
,
IPRange
As
(
    SELECT 
        StartIPInt / 16777216 As StartOctet1, 
        (StartIPInt - (StartIPInt / 16777216) * 16777216) /65536 As StartOctet2,
        (StartIPInt - ((StartIPInt / 65536) * 65536))/256 As StartOctet3,
        (StartIPInt - ((StartIPInt / 256) * 256)) As StartOctet4,
        EndIpInt / 16777216 As EndOctet1, 
        (EndIpInt - (EndIpInt / 16777216) * 16777216) /65536 As EndOctet2,
        (EndIpInt - ((EndIpInt / 65536) * 65536))/256 As EndOctet3,
        (EndIpInt - ((EndIpInt / 256) * 256)) As EndOctet4
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT  CAST(StartOctet1 AS VARCHAR(3)) + '.' + CAST(StartOctet2 AS VARCHAR(3)) + '.' + CAST(StartOctet3 AS VARCHAR(3)) + '.' + CAST(StartOctet4 AS VARCHAR(3))  StartIPAddress,
        CAST(EndOctet1 AS VARCHAR(3)) + '.' + CAST(EndOctet2 AS VARCHAR(3)) + '.' + CAST(EndOctet3 AS VARCHAR(3)) + '.' + CAST(EndOctet4 AS VARCHAR(3))  EndIPAddress
FROM IPRange
```

This gives the result:

```
StartIPAddress  EndIPAddress
1.0.0.0         1.0.0.255
```

> For a cleaner bit of code replace the IPRange CTE with:

```
IPRange
As
(
-- 1.0.0.0 0x0000000001000000
-- 0.1.0.0 0x0000000000010000
-- 0.0.1.0 0x0000000000000100
-- 0.0.0.255 0x00000000000000FF
    SELECT 
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(StartIPInt AS varbinary),0, 6) AS tinyInt) AS StartOctet1,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(StartIPInt AS varbinary),5, 2) AS tinyInt) AS StartOctet2,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(StartIPInt AS varbinary),6, 2) AS tinyInt) AS StartOctet3,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(StartIPInt AS varbinary),7, 2) AS tinyInt) AS StartOctet4,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(EndIPInt AS varbinary),0, 6) AS tinyInt) AS EndOctet1,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(EndIPInt AS varbinary),5, 2) AS tinyInt) AS EndOctet2,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(EndIPInt AS varbinary),6, 2) AS tinyInt) AS EndOctet3,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(EndIPInt AS varbinary),7, 2) AS tinyInt) AS EndOctet4
    FROM CTE
)
```